# How to update an object key value based on other key value in Array of object in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, carbon-design-system

I need to understand how we can update an object key value based on other key value in Array of object in React. Let' assume I have two different input field which is somehow link with the below formatted object, this object basically responsible for changing behavior of graph whenever I type something in input field. The below object passed into Graph component to show the changes whenever we type something in 2 input field.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { GaugeChart } from "@carbon/charts-react";
import "@carbon/charts/styles.css";

// in the data object graph behavior will update based on 
input provided in two input field and that will happen based on group key value

    const graphObj = {
        data: [
            {
                "group": "value",
                "value": 40
            },
            {
                "group": "delta",
                "value": 1000
            }
        ],
            options: {
            "resizable": true,
            "height": "250px",
            "width": "100%",
            "gauge": {
                "type": "semi",
                "status": "danger"
            }
        }
        };

const App = () => {
    
    const [graph, setGraph] = useState(graphObj); 
    const [formData, setFormData]  = useState({
        min: 40,
        max: 1000
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        
    }

 return (
        <>
        <GaugeChart
            data={graph.data}
            options={graph.options}>
        </GaugeChart>
        <br />
        <form>
            <input value={formData.min} onChange={handleChange}  />
            <input value={formData.max} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `min` in your state is `value` and `max` is `delta`, I would refactor a bit. Since your `graphObj` is a constant that we just want to add the `formData` to we can use useMemo that we remake the graphOptions object everytime form data updates.

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { GaugeChart } from "@carbon/charts-react";
import "@carbon/charts/styles.css";

const graphObj = {
  data: [
    {
      group: "value",
      value: 40,
    },
    {
      group: "delta",
      value: 1000,
    },
  ],
  options: {
    resizable: true,
    height: "250px",
    width: "100%",
    gauge: {
      type: "semi",
      status: "danger",
    },
  },
};

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    value: 40,
    delta: 1000,
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    // update the form data
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  // add form data to graph object
  const graphData = useMemo(() => {
    // formdata to { group: key, value: value } type
    return Object.keys(formData).map((key) => ({
      group: key,
      value: formData[key],
    }));
  }, [formData]);

  return (
    <>
      <GaugeChart data={graphData} options={graphObj.options}></GaugeChart>
      <br />
      <form>
        <input name={"value"} value={formData.value} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input name={"delta"} value={formData.delta} onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: some issue with graph.data i guess

Comment: Yeah, sorry noticed that `GaugeChart`did take data and options. Have updated the answer.